How to write a paper with word count limit?
What your preferred approach to writing a paper with a word count limit?
The two obvious approach are to

Try to write so that you don't exceed the word limit in the first place
write however you want, then shorten.

I would assume not worrying to much about the length and then shortening is easiest.
Regarding shortening:
How do you go about it?
Any specific suggestions on the use of LLMs?

another approach is just send the works to these journals that are possible to be explained appropriately within the page limits inherently, so select the journals based on all features of the work not just the title. A work that needs to be explained with a lot of details and experimental results, is not suitable to be shortened and sent as a short report, unless you want to report about it! (the same is true for the reverse situation)

I'd say the first step comes before you start really writing, in that you choose a scope for the paper that can fit.

Good points.
In this case though, my Professor chose the journal and it is my job to make the content fit the scope

I have always found that it is helpful to go way over and then force myself to find more efficient ways to write it; leads to a more readable paper ultimately.

Write around 20%-40% too much and shorten. The paper will be much better.

Find a different journal.

"Avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based, or that are likely to generate discussion rather than answers."

Journal/field dependent but one option is to put the least-important text into the supplemental document.

First regarding using LLM, it is increasingly becoming a commonplace to use AI to generate text for the papers. I think this practice should be discouraged not only by the editors/reviewers/publishers but also by the authors themselves (self accountability). Ironically speaking, there are so many cases reported on the LinkedIn showing the papers containing the unedited text from AI. The academic world is just getting weirder.
Regarding your question related to word count, it not always fixed word length but an estimated word length especially when it comes to long format publications such as journals, patents, and so forth. Yes the best bet should be write completely and then revise it considering the word count. You can also check other papers that have already been published in the same journal if they follow the word count guidelines strictly.

I disagree regarding LLMs. Using it to generate text is a different thing than having it revise your writing. I was thinking about shortening some formulations etc. not having the LLM basically rewrite your paper to a certain length...

@RandomName42 Having an LLM revise or rewrite rather than starting from scratch does not prevent it from hallucinating errors and changing the meaning of your writing. I would not advise it for anything important.

This is a Problem only if I don't understand the LLM's output enough to correct it or if I just blindly accept it, which should obviously not be the case.

@Bryan Krause hence why you proof read the revised text for errors. I see little issue in using an LLM to make sections of your writing more clear, concise and readable.
To be frank, I've always hated the way a lot of journals are written, You're almost expected to make your writing as obtuse as possible to look professional. So, writing your report in simple terms and then using an LLM to alter it into a professional format seems quite reasonable to me.

@BryanKrause: I'm not a native English speaker, and writing takes me a long time (even in my native laguage, and more so in English). It is easier and faster for me to understand written English, and to judge whether a text fits with what I want to say or not. Moreover, to put it the other way round: if someone's English is too poor to realize that LLM-generated text is ambiguous, any text they generate themselves may have the same problem.

@cbeleitesunhappywithSX Strongly disagree. The LLM can't know what the human author does and doesn't know/understand. The human author can. Revising is way more work than initially writing. Don't outsource your intellect to something that's provably not intelligent.

@ChellCPlus No, you're not expected to do that, so don't do it. Especially don't expect an LLM to "upscale" your understandable writing to something opaque. Terrible idea.

@RandomName42 Those checks are more work than the initial effort would be if they are done correctly; I'm suspicious that they ever are. In any case, by using an LLM you're letting statistics about what is found in writing generally to make decisions about what is and isn't important, with a model based on an old corpus and not actually intelligent in the first place. Do you really want that thing making decisions about what is and isn't important to your novel research publication? Writing isn't some game, it's a critical piece of the research process.

@Bryan Krause clearly often times having your writing changed so, that is conforms more with what is generally found writing is exactly what you want. In the end, arguing about whether LLMs are intelligent or not is beside the point. I am definitely able to judge whether the proposed changes are valid or not. Sure, it might in the end be inefficient but there is no risk involved as long as you are careful.

@RandomName42 No, there is risk involved that you might be able to alleviate if you are sufficiently careful. Multiple lawyers have now been sanctioned because they failed to fully cite-check LLM output and cited to non-existent authority.

@BryanKrause Is your assertion that LLMs are "provably" not intelligent backed up by proof? Judging from personal interaction with these systems (Claude-3-Opus and the latest version of GPT-4) I would say they clearly are intelligent to some extent and that it is also clear that they understand to some extent (albeit maybe in a p-zombie way, obviously). Indeed, I would even say that small models that can run on an ordinary laptop like Mistral-7b have some understanding of what they say.

@Polytropos You must have a very different concept of "intelligence".

@BryanKrause It is much worse. Intelligence is one of the things that I do not in fact have a clear "concept" of. But I recognize it when it's there on a case-by-case basis (maybe with some error rate - who can tell these days).


How do you go about it?

Cut out a lot of discussion, replace all convoltued forms ("it is possbile" with "may") ...

Any specific suggestions on the use of LLMs?

Yes: check carefully if and where the text you give is saved. You may be breaking confidentiality, in the not so far future you may be exposing yourself to plagiarism (what if the LLM you use is sentient and submit the publication before you?)

I like your scenario. An LLM with a scientific ego.

+1 for checking carefully. However, preparing a publication means that the risk of breaking confidentiality is low since the text is anyways meant to be public. (IMHO generating texts for internal use is a very different scenario in that respect. And yes, there may accidentally be confidential things in drafts that are removed before publication - but then the baseline to compare to would be the risk of accidentally exposing confidential information and not realiziing this before publication).

Wrt LLM submitting faster: I guess for now the risk would be rather the LLM generating text for someone else who then publishes faster. Anyways, writing e.g. with version control means that there are time stamps which can be used to contest such plagiarism.
(And in turn, one should maybe be careful when the LLM expresses good ideas that were not in the input...)

My dad taught me a good rule: delete the second sentence in every paragraph. Sounds weird, but it's amazing how often it works. If you don't believe it, try it on some of the answers to your question.

I would recommend you do both: write a first draft concisely, then revise to shorten if necessary. It is good practice to be short and to the point (step 1) even if you do not have a word limit. Your readers and reviewers will thank you for it.
This is not easy, especially at first. You will get better with experience.
I have not tried using LLMs to revise text. I agree that this is a task they may be good at. However, I would recommend you revise the result thoroughly; LLMs do have a tendency to hallucinate, and I would be very careful as to whether their shortened text still conveys correct information and kept the important bits.

The only correct answer to this is, "Do what works for you," because there's no reason that anyone else's work process should align with how your mind works.
But in the spirit of helpful examples:

Outline
Write at length
Trim
Trim
Trim
Polish
Trim

My natural writing style is expansive and verbose.  The only way I can work my way around to 'terse' is by writing what I want to write and hacking away at it.
The same applies to page count maxima, which are arguably even worse.  I've never been so tempted to throw my laptop out the window, as the day I added a word-- a short word-- to a paper draft on Page 1, and the various rules in the venue's mandatory Word template turned that into two or three extra lines on Page N+1 of an N-page-max paper.

You missed a few steps.  8. Polish.  9. Polish.  10. Trim.  11.  Add a section of explanation.  12.  Trim.  13. Trim.  14. Curse the Writing Gods.  15. Polish. 16. Remove the section added in step 11.  17. Revise.  18. Trim.  19. Polish. &c.

@XanderHenderson I had to cut those to maintain the word count.

+1 because I came here to give the same answer and the opposite example :D . My writing style (at least in academic wiriting) was rather dense, my first draft of a paper was usually below the page/word limit, so what I did was 1. Outline, 2. write, 3. expand explanations here and there, 4. polish, 5. find that one word that makes LaTeX wrap every paragraph so oddly that the bibliography ends up beyond the page limit, 6. polish, 7. upload a few hours before the submission deadline, even though the paper feels far from perfect.

I tackle this by thinking in units much larger than words. For example, in paragraphs, or pages, or sections. Take a document you've done before, and see how many words the paragraphs tend to be, just roughly. Many of mine are 200 words, so if I have a "budget" of 1000 words, that's 5 paragraphs.  You can't express 20 ideas in 5 paragraphs, right? This sets the scope of what you will write.
If you have 5000 words, they will probably be introduction, thing, thing, thing, conclusion, each about 1000 words. Or of course you may have required sections like Summary, Background, Method, etc.  What is a long one of those for you? What is a short one?
This will let you get the scope right. You won't find yourself needing to cut a thing in half. Then you may find that you need to chop 10% or add 10%, and that can be done by removing a sentence here and there, or perhaps shortening some wordy phrases and dropping "filler" like "with this in mind, we proceeded to perform the operations required to complete the" . This sort of work can be very frustrating, so don't start until you've got roughly the right number of sections, pages, and paragraphs. Only then, refine the word count.

Several other answers make excellent points already, so I won’t repeat them, but to add one point they don’t cover: Outline extra-carefully, with the word/page count in mind.  (I’ll use page limits here since that’s more common in my field.)  This also has a lot in common with planning slides for a talk, where you have a fixed time limit which (for planning) can often roughly be translated to numbers of slides.
For a tight page count, I’d start by making an outline including estimated page counts, something like

Title, abstract: c 1/2 page
Introduction: 2–3 pages
Technical background: 1–2 pages
Definitions + basic properties of reticulated widgets: 2–3 pages
Main proof of frobnicating theorem: 1–2 pages

so I can make sure my outline looks well-balanced and feasible.  Then I start drafting based on that outline; as I draft, I keep the outline in mind, and both shape the draft to fit the outline, and adjust the outline as necessary to fit the growing draft — when (inevitably) some sections need more space than I’d expected, and (hopefully) others turn out to work more concisely.  If too many sections are demanding more space, and all are feeling as concise as I can get them, then that’s the time to cut more concisely.
What I do not recommend (at least, it doesn’t work for me) is just writing first without thinking about the word/page/time limit, and then trying to cut/compress it afterwards.  One of the most frustrating writing tasks I’ve ever attempted was cutting a c.24-page draft I was very happy with down to 20 pages — no paragraph could be cut without weakening the whole structure.  In the end I think we just submitted as 24 pages and trusted to the journal’s generosity.  Different space constraints are often best suited to a different outline and selection of material entirely — e.g. a longer version gives space to present technical details; in a short version, rather than presenting them unreadably densely, it may be better to cut them entirely and set up a black-box abstraction of what they provide, which can then push towards a different organisation of the surrounding material.  So keeping the length constraints in mind from the start helps to find an exposition well-suited to them, and avoid too much backtracking later.

I would recommend a mixture of both methods, and add a third component:
(3) Prioritize the parts of the argument that are really important. Not everything in your work must go into the paper. It's always possible to put an extended version on arxiv or similar.
I can't stress that last point enough. I find it not uncommon when reviewing papers to encounter the case where the authors have worked hard to cram everything they found out about their scientific question into the page limit of the conference/journal they submitted to, only to end up with a paper where half of the results were weak or partly wrong or at least insufficiently supported by evidence or not fully worked out.
These hurt their chances of getting accepted, even if the core contribution is good. I would in those cases much rather have reviewed a 15-page paper containing only the core contributions and referring the interested reader to the 42-page extended version, than the 30-page thing the authors submitted because they were afraid to leave something out, and maybe that the short version would insufficiently dazzle the reviewers.
